# Docker install fails on OSx

Tags: macos, docker

I am trying to install new Docker on OSx.

It fails with following error.

> Installation Failed.

Also the window opens where I can see two utilities:

- Docker Quick Terminal
- Kinematic

When I click Docker Quick Terminal I can type:

```
docker info
```

But when I type:

```
docker run
```

I get the error.

[image: Image install failed]

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
Password:
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
bash-4.3$
```

Comment: Did you install boot2docker?

Comment: Do I need to install that ? I had it earlier but removed it before this

Comment: I reinstalled boot2docker and then started install , still get the same error.

Comment: Thanks , the install is successful now. Do i need to remove boot2docker and install the new package again ?

Comment: I was not aware of the new docker toolbox, so go ahead and follow the answer

Answer (score 13):

Just ran into the same thing.  I did have a virtual machine running but was still getting that error when I tried to use the command line.  When I ran `docker-machine env default` to see the state of my docker VM named *default* I was prompted to run a command, `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` to initialize my shell.   That step got everything working for me.

The details, as it turns out, are at the top of the [README for docker/machine](https://github.com/docker/machine) on github.

Answer (score 8):

Check if vbox is running; if not, start it (replace `default` with your vbox name):

```
$ docker-machine start default
```

And then do as Kevin above replied:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Comment: Solved it for me too, after having issues with `docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

Answer (score 4):

Docker just changed the way you [install](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/) on Mac OS X and Windows. Now you install a [Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/toolbox). They also changed the name of `boot2docker` to `docker-machine`

```
Note: This release of Docker deprecates the Boot2Docker command line
in favor of Docker Machine. Use the Docker Toolbox to install Docker
Machine as well as the other Docker tools.
```

So remove any installation for boot2docker of you are installing from the [Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/toolbox). Before you install make sure you stop any [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) completely on your Mac OS X machine.

You can also remove the installation of [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) if you have it and let the Docker [Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/toolbox) install it for you

Before you can run any container with

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

you need to have your docker-machine running. Do a

```
ps -Af | grep VBox
```

and see if your Virtual Machine for docker-machine is running. You should see something like

```
VBoxHeadless docker-machine ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Got the same toolbox error at the end, but tests at the time worked so I moved on.  After reboot, `docker info` shows `Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.`, so if `ps` shows no VBox process, it means...what failed on install?  setup of the daemon?

Comment: Oops, when I started my `Docker Quickstart Terminal` all was well.